# Ignore internationalisation in Django Template CSS font file

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have defined in my Django Template file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "EmojiSymbols";
    src: url('EmojiSymbols-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

When I implement Internalisation, all things are working find except I keep getting (example of one of the language selected)

```
Not Found: /en/EmojiSymbols-Regular.woff
[17/Mar/2016 12:16:31] "GET /en/EmojiSymbols-Regular.woff HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Not Found: /en/EmojiSymbols-Regular.woff/
[17/Mar/2016 12:16:31] "GET /en/EmojiSymbols-Regular.woff/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1730
```

How do I make Django ignore internationalise CSS font source? Or do I have to manually tells it as seen in [Manually Switch languages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates)?  Though there were no translation (aka {% trans...) in the CSS block of code.  Any help please.

Here is the template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}"{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %} dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
{% load pages_tags mezzanine_tags i18n future staticfiles %}

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="keywords" content="{% block meta_keywords %}{% endblock %}">
<meta name="description" content="{% block meta_description %}{% endblock %}">
<title>{% block meta_title %}{% endblock %}{% if settings.SITE_TITLE %} | {{ settings.SITE_TITLE }}{% endif %}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "img/favicon.ico" %}">

{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap-rtl.css" %}">
{% endif %}
{% endcompress %}

{% compress js %}
<script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/bootstrap-extras.js" %}">   
  </script>
{% endcompress %}

{% block local_style %}
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "EmojiSymbols";
    src: url('EmojiSymbols-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 200%;
}
.emj {
    font-family: "EmojiSymbols";
    line-height:1;
}
</style>
{% endblock local_style %}

{% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

Please note.  All webpages are working in all the supported language fine with no problems.  The Not Found error was only shown on console when for the font file.

Comment: could you please provide a full sample html template (to see what you load etc.), the middleware classes that are configured, and the relevant i18n settings please?

Comment: Zsepi - thank you.  All pages are working find.  But in the console the source file for the font shows error in the console.  On user front end, all are working well.